# disable the last item in the link

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular1.6. I'm trying to disable the last link in the sidenav. But somehow the first item is disabled Here is the code and [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SekRaA9hJkfq3aZPwrKx?p=preview)

```
<li ng-repeat="item in nav.sideNavListOne" ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="[{true: 'disabled'}[$index == $last]]">
   <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">{{$index+5}}.&nbsp;{{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you need angular for this? Wouldn't just css do the trick?

`li:last-of-type > a { pointer-events: none }`

just put that rule relative to the parent `ul`?

Comment: The `angular` tag is for Angular 2.x+ and the `angularjs` tag is for Angular 1.x. Since your question is for angular 1.x, please remove the `angular` tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$last` is a boolean, as you can read in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> $last boolean => true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

the correct syntax would be

```
ng-class="{'disabled': $last}"
```

if `$last` is true, it will add the class `disabled`.

So the entire line is

```
<li ng-repeat="item in nav.sideNavListOne" ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{'disabled': $last}" >
```

Here is a working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mfvuxskHtthhyfzsjxSx?p=preview)

As the comments point out, you can also do this outside from angular, with pure css - this answer is the angular way as you asked.

Answer (score 3):

`$index` is a number and `$last` will be a Boolean.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in nav.sideNavListOne" ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="[{true: 'disabled'}[$last]]">
```

Just use `$last`